# PAM "remember me" with timeout option for 2FA?

Tags: authentication, pam

Is it possible for PAM to remember that a second factor authentication has passed for a short period of time, e.g. an hour? This would have to be keyed to a user and IP address.

For example:

- Log in as `tom` from `1.2.3.4`, password, **2FA**, logged in.
- Log in as `tom` from `1.2.3.4`, password, logged in.
- Log in as `tom` from `1.2.3.4`, public key auth, logged in.
- Log in as `tom` from `200.2.3.4`, public key auth, **2FA**, logged in.
- Wait an hour, log in as `tom` from `1.2.3.4`, public key auth, **2FA**, logged in.